# Why is state change in my function component not continuously triggering re-render?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn more in-depth the render cycle of function components.
As I'm testing different scenarios of triggering re-renders by experimenting with useEffect and useState, I encounter an example where changing the state continuously(in fact, an intended infinite loop) does not cause the render to be triggered continuously.

Consider the code sample below or on CodeSandbox at: https://co5tj.csb.app/

I was really expecting the render cycle to go into an infinite loop, but it doesn't. It always stops after the 3rd render, as seen in the console log, i

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [myText, setMyText] = useState("Waiting for text...");
  useEffect(() => {
    function getMyTextData() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setMyText("Hello, here is some text.");
      }, 3000);
    }
    getMyTextData();
  }, [myText]);

  console.log("triggering render...  state = " + myText);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{myText}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't lead to an infinite recursion because the second time `setMyText` is called it doesn't actually result in a state update - because the current state is equal to the next state, so the update is skipped.

Changing it to:

```js
        setMyText(myText + "more text");
```

will make it infinite.

Comment: Yes, I tried your code change to make it trigger infinitely.  However, what I don't understand is, with my original code, why there is a 3rd render. It would have already stopped triggering another render after it has rendered the 2nd time. Like you said, the next state equal to the current state, so it would not have triggered the 3rd render, but it did.